# Proof of cotangent product formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the series expansion for the cotangent function, $$\pi cot(\pi z)= 1/z + 2\sum_n \frac{z}{z^2-n^2}$$ given here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function

What I am confused about is the logarithmic derivative. Specifically, it seems to me that they are using that this is the same as taking logs of the sine product formula and differentiating. The issue is that $\log(sin(\pi z))$ isn't continuous when $sin(\pi z)$ lies on the negative real axis. So how does one take the derivative? If instead one uses logarithmic derivative to mean $f'/f$ then how does one show that the product become a sum without using logs?

Comment: The $\log(\sin(\pi z))$ is differentiable everywhere it is defined, but as usual, the logarithm is multi-valued, however when differentiated, the multi-valuedness is gone. The same problem arises when differentiating $\log(z).$

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to fix a branch of the logarithm, say the one on $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 0]$. Whenever $z \neq 0,$ you can find a branch of the complex logarithm defined on a neighborhood of $z$. So we can just take the derivative on such a neighborhood, in your case a neighborhood of $\sin \pi z$, and I think this justifies it.